# JPA un-schedules deletion of orphans and polymorphic collections

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Kindly look at the code.

```
    for (CowRow row : entity.getCowRows()) {
        em.remove(row.getCowRowData());
        em.remove(row);
    }
    entity.getCowRows().clear();
```

Where

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cowrow")
public class CowRow {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Cow cow;

    private int rowNumber;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "cowRow", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private CowRowData cowRowData;
//accessors here
}
```

CowRowData is a parent entity for CowPriceTag and CowReasoning. "entity" is a Cow which contains this:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "cow", orphanRemoval = true)
private Collection<CowRow> cowRows;
```

On flush, this code fragment produces a log:

```
2018-05-07 11:20:21.351 TRACE 15892 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade    : Processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: ru.dz.bis.entities.Cow
2018-05-07 11:20:21.353 TRACE 15892 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade    : Done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: ru.dz.bis.entities.Cow
```

There are some more records about cascading, none of them about CowRow or CowRow.

However if I remove that "for" loop - one would expect that clearing a collection will cause removal of orphaned CowRow instances. However, for some reason, the deletion gets un-scheduled, with this weird log:

```
2018-05-07 11:40:49.342 TRACE 19739 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade    : Processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: ru.dz.bis.entities.Cow
2018-05-07 11:40:49.343 TRACE 19739 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade    : Done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: ru.dz.bis.entities.Cow
2018-05-07 11:40:49.343 TRACE 19739 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade    : Processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: ru.dz.bis.entities.Folder
2018-05-07 11:40:49.344 TRACE 19739 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade    : Done processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: ru.dz.bis.entities.Folder
2018-05-07 11:40:49.345 TRACE 19739 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade    : Processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: ru.dz.bis.entities.CowRow
2018-05-07 11:40:49.346 TRACE 19739 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction   : Cascading to persist on flush: ru.dz.bis.entities.CowRowData
2018-05-07 11:40:49.346 TRACE 19739 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener        : Persistent instance of: ru.dz.bis.entities.CowRowData
2018-05-07 11:40:49.347 TRACE 19739 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.e.i.DefaultPersistEventListener      : Ignoring persistent instance
20
```

If orphanRemoval is working, why is JPA persisting a CowRow? I cleared Cow.cowRows, JPA is supposed to scheduled those rows for deletion. And there is no mentioning of un-scheduling in the log!

Ok, let's try something else. Let's just do "em.remove(row.getCowRowData())" in a "for" loop. Now I see this:

```
2018-05-07 11:54:26.869 TRACE 22914 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade    : Processing cascade ACTION_PERSIST_ON_FLUSH for: ru.dz.bis.entities.CowRow
2018-05-07 11:54:26.870 TRACE 22914 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction   : Cascading to persist on flush: ru.dz.bis.entities.CowRowData
2018-05-07 11:54:26.873 TRACE 22914 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener        : Deleted instance of: ru.dz.bis.entities.CowRowData
2018-05-07 11:54:26.878 TRACE 22914 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.e.i.DefaultPersistEventListener      : un-scheduling entity deletion [[ru.dz.bis.entities.CowPriceTag#8]]
```

So 1) there is a difference between relying on orphanRemoval and doing manual removal, 2) JPA is for some reason processing cascade persist for RowData, 3) when processing this persist cascade, JPA says it deletes a CowRowData (why now? possibly because of orphanRemoval?), 4) and right after that, it cancels the deletion, like because this CowRowData refers to CowPriceTag (OK but it's the same entity - its subclass! and on top of that, it's deleted!)

And only if I do "em.remove(row)" in a loop as well, the code works as designed. Though even now not quite: deleting row.getCowRowData() should make CowRowData orphan (in CowRow->CowRowData) and schedule its removal (similarly to CascadeType.REMOVE in this case), that does not happen.

What does that all mean?

Maybe orphanRemoval does not work with polymorphic collections? Or is it me?